ACF WPML frontend form: Load form with duplicated content for editing
An ACF form in the frontend of a bilingual site (de/en) creates a data record.
On submit, a second data record in the second language is saved (WPML hook wpml_copy_post_to_language).
How can I display a form with the data in the second language for editing immediateley after submit?
